# How to output wp_enqueue_style() in HTML head instead of footer

Tags: theme-development, wp-enqueue-style, wp-head

I added some actions to `wp_enqueue_scripts` to load my custom css and js files in the header section by using `wp_head();` right before the closing `</head>` tag.

```
function mytheme_scripts(){
    // Load our main stylesheet
    wp_enqueue_style( 'mytheme-css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/styles.min.css', false);
    // Load concatenated vendors JavaScript file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'vendors-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/vendors.min.js');
    // Load our main JavaScript file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'mytheme-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/app.min.js', array( 'vendors-js' ));

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts', false);
```

While both `*.js` files are loaded in the HTML `<head>` section the custom `*.css` file is loaded in the footer of the page (probably triggered by `wp_footer()`).

I have read about the fact that `wp_enqueue_scripts()` could be placed anywhere in the source code since any earlier WP version. I've also read that `wp_enqueue_script()` has a parameter `$in_footer` to control the output location. However, `wp_enqueue_style()` doesn't have such an option.

Now, how can I have my custom stylesheet link be placed in HTML head section without hard-coding it into `header.php`?

Comment: You have a serious issue somewhere, styles are never loaded in the footer, and should also never be as `link` tags are invalid outside the `head` tags. This is not default behavior. Something broke something else as it is impossible for styles to load in the footer. Coming from your previous question, make sure that you did not remove something that is truly needed.

Comment: Here is what I removed according to my previous question
http://pastebin.com/k2XjTV3E

Oh, and I'm not the the only one with this issue, see https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_enqueue_style-add-to-head

Comment: OK, I have tested your code, by removing the three following hooks from `wp_head` causes a lot of issues, so you need to remove it from your code, `locale_stylesheet`, `wp_generator` and `wp_print_styles`. Clear your browser cache and restart your browser after removing that code. Everything should work normally

Comment: What also strange is @Bunjip in your code, maybe it is lack of knowledge from my side, the code you show here <code>add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts', false);</code> , what is that <code>false</code> doing there?

Comment: @Charles, that's a good question ;). Guess, that comes from playing around with all kind of parameters and forgetting to clean off some trials...

Comment: @PieterGoosen, that resolves my issue, once again. Great stuff. I'd be happy to mark another answer of you to be the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

hook into init action on your initial plugin function

```
add_action('init', array(__CLASS__, 'your_function_within_class'));
```

and add the function

```
public static function your_function_within_class()
{
    
    wp_register_style('myfirstplugin-admin-css', '/wp-content/plugins/myfirstplugin/assets/style.css', false);
    
    wp_enqueue_style('myfirstplugin-admin-css');
}
```

hope this help

Answer (score -1):

You can change the hook to `get_footer` so files are inserted in the footer

try changing

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_scripts', false);
```

to

```
add_action( 'get_footer', 'mytheme_scripts', false);
```

Comment: Please explain downvote :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the downvote is because this answer in no way addresses the question. Specifically, OP asked how to load css in the header, where your solution would cause them to load in the footer.